# Export in Google Earth Engine a NDTI with same name of an original image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I try to export a NDTI of an image collection with the same name of original image, but when I try it inside a function it doesn't work and the name apear this way:

```
ee.ComputedObject({"type": "Invocation", "arguments": {"object": {"type": "ArgumentRef", "value": null}, "property": "system:GRANULE_ID"},  "functionName": "Element.get"})ndti
```

Sample of script:

```
var calc_NDVI_l5 = function(image) {
  var m = image.get("system:GRANULE_ID");
  print(m);
  var ndti = image.normalizedDifference(['B11', 'B12'])
    .rename("ndti");
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: ndti,
    description: m + 'ndti',
    scale: 20,
    region: geometry,
    maxPixels: 2e10,
  });
  return image.addBands(ndti);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `description` in `Export.image.toDrive()` must be a [client-side](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) object. The simplest thing you can do is `m.getInfo() + 'ndti'`. `getInfo()` will block the GUI though, so maybe you're better off with this:

```
  m.evaluate(function (granuleId) {
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: ndti,
      description: granuleId + 'ndti',
      scale: 20,
      region: geometry,
      maxPixels: 2e10,
    });
  })
```